# Multiple Operation in Pandas dataframe simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Primary dataframe D1:

```
PRCESS_NO   VALUE   COUNT   TIME
18          25855   69      13:41:56
19          10254   8       13:42:14
20          10254   4       13:42:20
21          68522   18      13:42:29
22          68522   75      13:42:33
23          25855   21      13:42:37
24          10254   658     13:42:53
25          10254   84      13:42:59
```

D2 dataframe:

```
PRCESS_NO   VALUE   COUNT   TIME
21          68522   12      14:32:25
22          68522   10      14:42:39
23          25855   54      14:38:25
```

I want to update primary dataframe D1 with values from D2 dataframe as per the below mentioned condition:

1. Add the Values of VALUE & COUNT Column (D1.VALUE + D2.VALUE, D1.COUNT + D2.COUNT)
2. Update the D1 TIME Column with Values from D2 TIME Column.

Final D1 Dataframe:

```
PRCESS_NO   VALUE   COUNT   TIME
18          25855   69      13:41:56
19          10254   8       13:42:14
20          10254   4       13:42:20
21          68522   30      14:32:25
22          68522   85      14:42:39
23          25855   75      14:38:25
24          10254   658     13:42:53
25          10254   84      13:42:59
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
cols = ['VALUE','COUNT']
D1 = D1.set_index('PRCESS_NO')
D2 = D2.set_index('PRCESS_NO')

D1[cols] = D1[cols].add(D2[cols], fill_value=0).astype(int)
D1['TIME'] = D2['TIME'].combine_first(D1['TIME'])
D1 = D1.reset_index()
print (D1)
   PRCESS_NO   VALUE  COUNT      TIME
0         18   25855     69  13:41:56
1         19   10254      8  13:42:14
2         20   10254      4  13:42:20
3         21  137044     30  14:32:25
4         22  137044     85  14:42:39
5         23   51710     75  14:38:25
6         24   10254    658  13:42:53
7         25   10254     84  13:42:59
```

Or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) `sum` and `last`:

```
D1 = (pd.concat([D1,D2])
        .groupby('PRCESS_NO', as_index=False)
        .agg({'VALUE':'sum', 'COUNT':'sum', 'TIME':'last'}))
print (D1)
   PRCESS_NO   VALUE  COUNT      TIME
0         18   25855     69  13:41:56
1         19   10254      8  13:42:14
2         20   10254      4  13:42:20
3         21  137044     30  14:32:25
4         22  137044     85  14:42:39
5         23   51710     75  14:38:25
6         24   10254    658  13:42:53
7         25   10254     84  13:42:59
```

Comment: Sir, What will happen if a new row is found. I want to add the entire row from D2 to D1.

Comment: @Pravat - hmmm, it add to `D1` by `PRCESS_NO` values, it should working. Can you explain more?

Comment: Yes Sir, its working. Thanks a lot for the help. One more doubt, I want to have a separate column which will keep the ONLY Last value of "VALUE" column also. is it possible..?

Comment: One more doubt, I want to have a separate column which will keep the ONLY Last value of "VALUE" column also. is it possible..?

Comment: @Pravat - then `(pd.concat([D1,D2])
        .groupby('PRCESS_NO', as_index=False)
        .agg({'VALUE':['sum', 'last'], 'COUNT':'sum', 'TIME':'last'}))` and `D1.columns = D1.columns.map('_'.join)` is necessary